# Call a callback function inside for of loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, for-of-loop

I'm making a request with a for of loop to delete all the cart elements, but it doesn't work as expected. Loop works for first iteration but API returns an error in the second iteration.

I think it's a logical error, what's the problem with this code?

My try:

```
module.exports.removeAllCartItems = (token) => {
    this.getCart(token, (error, data) => {
        if(error){
            Sentry.captureException(error);
        }

        const cartItems = data.items
        console.log('------cart items----------')
        console.log(cartItems)
        console.log('------cart items----------')
        for(item of cartItems){
            let productId = item.productId
            let variantId = item.variant.product_id
            console.log('--------item one by one---------')
            console.log(item)
            console.log('--------item one by one---------')
           
            this.removeItem(token, productId, variantId, (error, data)=> {
        
                if(error) {
                    Sentry.captureException(error);             
                }
                console.log('------data-------')
                console.log(data)
                console.log('******data*******')
            } )
            
        }

        
    })
}
```

Remove item method:

```
module.exports.removeItem = (token, productId, variantId, callback) => {
    const url = urlBase + "/removeItem" + `?secretKey=${secretKey}`;
    request(
        {
            url: url,
            method: "DELETE",
            json: true,
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            body: {
                secretKey: `${secretKey}`,
                productId: productId,
                variantId: variantId,
            },
        },
        (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                Sentry.captureException(error);
                callback(errMessage, undefined);
            } else {
                const data = response.body;
                callback(undefined, data);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Console output:

```
------cart items----------
[
  {
    variant: {
      variation_values: [Object],
      price: 475,
      product_id: '883360541280',
      orderable: true
    },
    _id: '62403a55ec05ea0024e9d965',
    productId: '21736758',
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    variant: {
      variation_values: [Object],
      price: 58.99,
      product_id: '701643411498',
      orderable: true
    },
    _id: '62403b7eec05ea0024e9d966',
    productId: '25589208',
    quantity: 1
    variation_values: { color: 'P2V', size: '42' },
    price: 475,
    product_id: '883360541280',
    orderable: true
  },
  _id: '62403a55ec05ea0024e9d965',
  productId: '21736758',
  quantity: 1
}
--------item one by one---------
--------item one by one---------
{
  variant: {
    variation_values: { color: 'JJ3WCXX', size: '9MD' },
    price: 58.99,
    product_id: '701643411498',
    orderable: true
  },
  _id: '62403b7eec05ea0024e9d966',
  productId: '25589208',
  quantity: 1
}
--------item one by one---------
------data-------
{
  _id: '6240398eec05ea0024e9d962',
  secretKey: '<secretKey>',
  userId: '623dfb884083b000243cc4a7',
  items: [
    {
      variant: [Object],
      _id: '62403a55ec05ea0024e9d965',
      productId: '21736758',
      quantity: 1
    }
  ],
  __v: 6
}
******data*******
------data-------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Internal Server Error</pre>
</body>
</html>

******data*******
```

Why API returns internal server error in the second iteration, is it about my code or something else, any idea ?

I make it work with that way but still dont know why first implementation doesn't work

```
module.exports.removeAllCartItems = (token) => {
    this.getCart(token, async (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            Sentry.captureException(error);
        }

        const cartItems = data.items;

        for (item of cartItems) {
            let productId = item.productId;
            let variantId = item.variant.product_id;

            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.removeItem(token, productId, variantId, (error, data) => {
                    if (error) {
                        reject(error);
                        Sentry.captureException(error);
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                });
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What's that lonely `this` referring to in your function? That's a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: this refers to a request function in the same .js file so I access with this keyword is it problem ?

Comment: ...since I can't see the rest of your module, I can only say that it looks very odd: When you set `module.exports.removeAllCartItems = function ...` that means `exports` can't be a class. And when `exports` is not a class, then `this` is not going to be bound to anything useful inside `removeAllCartItems`, or requires explicit binding via `.call()` or `.apply()`. So if it works for you, fine. I think it looks fishy.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All your functions (`getCart()`, `removeItem()`) are asynchronous. `removeAllCartItems()` needs to be asynchronous, too.

Introduce a callback into `removeAllCartItems()`, exactly like the other two have. Call it either when any error occurs, or when you're done (i.e., when no items to remove are left).

```
module.exports.removeAllCartItems = (token, callback) => {
    this.getCart(token, (error, cart) => {
        if (error) {
            Sentry.captureException(error);
            callback(error);
            return;
        }
        let remainingItems = cart.items.length;
        if (remainingItems === 0) callback();

        for (let item of cart.items) {
            this.removeItem(token, item.productId, item.variant.product_id, (error, data) => {
                if (error) {
                    Sentry.captureException(error);
                    callback(error);
                    return;
                }
                remainingItems--;
                if (remainingItems === 0) callback();
            });
        }    
    });
};
```

In the calling code, use the callback.

```
removeAllCartItems(token, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        // display error somehow
        return;
    }
    // display success somehow
});
```

---

Unrelated thought on your API design: Your current `removeItem()` function has this signature:

```
removeItem(token, productId, variantId)
```

it should probably have this signature instead:

```
removeItem(token, item)
```

where `item` can either be an `item` instance (convenient for loops like in this case) or possibly an item ID.

The function can then access `item.productId`, and `item.variant.product_id` or whatever else it needs internally, that should not be the calling code's concern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not design the API,  just access it.

Comment: @AssSoonAsPossiblee Yeah, that was just a thought that crossed my mind. Does the rest work?

Comment: It still works for first iteration, It can delete the first item in the cart but not the second one. API returns internal server error for the second iteration as a response it can be a problem about API.

Comment: @AssSoonAsPossiblee Well I corrected the general mistake in your approach, this will become relevant later. It's impossible for me to say which error occurs, you need to share more details. My suspicion is that it's related to modifying the collection you are iterating over.

Comment: When I use promise,, I don't know why but I can delete all cart items.

Comment: @AssSoonAsPossiblee Interesting. Without seeing the actual error, it's all guesswork, but the non-promise version calls `removeItem()` N times *immediately*. Maybe the `removeItem()` method does not like to be called another time while it's still busy. Your promise implementation only calls the next `removeItem()` after the previous one has returned. This is the main difference between the two.

Comment: I thought the same, the API might not be accepting fast consecutive requests

Comment: @AssSoonAsPossiblee When you have no details other than "500 Internal Server Error", no logs, no nothing... then yeah, that would be the reasonable assumption. Also hints at pretty bad API design.